# Macbook retina 15 3 external screens

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen, hdmi

I've read reviews about 3 external screens for late 2013 macbook pro 15 retina, and looks like there are different opinions about that. Some of videos I saw demonstrates the fact that it is possible connect all three screens at once.

But before buying all necessary components I would like to show what kind of screens I would like to purchase and what type of adapters I am about to use.

Could you please take a look for my build and let me know your opinion if it is going to work and if not, could you please describe correct way of connecting it.

3 BENQ Screens (1920 x 1080, 2 ms, VGA, DVI-D, HDMI)

2 screens will be connected using [mini display port to HDMI Adapter](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Proxima-Direct%C2%AE-Mini-Displayport-adapter/dp/B005J0XB7A/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1405542278&sr=8-1&keywords=mini%20displayport%20to%20hdmi)

1 screen will be connected directly on HDMI port.

Do you think that build would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had problems with third party video adaptors, so I'd be hesitant to try that. Since your monitors have DVI ports, I'd go with two [Apple Mini Display Port to DVI adaptors](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB570Z/B/mini-displayport-to-dvi-adapter) and use an HDMI cable for the third monitor.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Have you tried plugin two screens on DVI and one on HDMI, does it work? Because some people says that they able connect only two screens at once.

Comment: Yes. I wasn't able to keep that setup for long, but it worked well while it lasted.

Comment: Right! Thanks a lot! What happened with setup, did it broke your mac?

Comment: No, Somebody else needed a monitor and I had four.